# After fetching raw data, where can I parse raw data in react-redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, axios, reselect

I just fetched some raw data from a server and after that I need to parse the data before I render them on a component.

So where should I put the code to parse data? In the reducer or in the action? I think it should be put in reducer, but is that suitable?

Comment: Where are you fetching the data? Are you using redux-thunk or redux-saga?

Comment: Please, show example of your fetchData action to be more explicit

Comment: componentWillMount(){ this.props.getMapData()  },  I am using redux-promise instead of thunk or saga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be dispatching an action that kicks off a request to the server for the information you need. This can be done using either [sagas](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) or [thunks](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). Both are good solutions. Send the request in the thunk or saga and handle the response in the thunk or saga. The response handler should do whatever processing is necessary on the data and then should dispatch another action to update the redux store with the new data.